# .prop not updating visual style of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two checkboxes, I need to hide and uncheck one whilst the other is checked. So far, it unchecks it programmatically, however not visually for the user, so if the check box re-appears, it will look like it is checked, while it is not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remote-only-check").click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#remote-ok-check").prop('checked', false);
        if (!$("#remote-ok-check").is(':checked')) {
          //this works!
          console.log("remote ok is switched off");
        }
        $("#remote-ok").removeClass("active");
      } else {
        $("#remote-ok").addClass("active");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 59, 222);
  border-image: initial;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 59, 222);
}

#remote-ok{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

#remote-ok.active{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group standard">
  <label class="control-label" for="id_location">Location</label>
  <input placeholder="Toronto" type="text" name="location" id="id_location" required="" class=" form-control standard" maxlength="200">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" id="remote-only"><input type="checkbox" id="remote-only-check" value=""><span>Remote Only</span></label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline active" id="remote-ok"><input type="checkbox" id="remote-ok-check" value=""><span>Remote OK</span></label>
</div>
```

**NB:** `.active` just hides the other check box using `opacity` and `visibility`.

Comment: If you have any question related to css, please do post the css as well, not just the js and html.

Comment: Hi Chris, just added

Comment: Please post when you run your jquery, is it in a document ready?

Comment: Yeah, it's wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: Your html has a syntax error: replace <input type="checkbox" id="remote-ok-check value=""> with <input type="checkbox" id="remote-ok-check" value="">

Comment: Please explain; if you click "remote only" you want the "remote ok" to be hidden AND if the "remote ok" was checked, when it is made visible again, you want it to be unchecked?

Comment: Yeah, spot on Chris.

Comment: Looks like SuperDJ fixed your typo when converting to a snippet.  Adding jquery and the snippet now works as you describe it *should* work.  So there appears not to be any issue other than a typo.

Comment: Ah you're right guys, it was a syntax error in the HTML - that's infuriating. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you that it is quite easy to **not** use jQuery.

```js
const remoteOnlyCheck = document.querySelector('#remote-only-check');
const remoteOkCheck = document.querySelector('#remote-ok-check');
const remoteOk = document.querySelector('#remote-ok');

remoteOnlyCheck.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(remoteOnlyCheck.checked);
  if(remoteOnlyCheck.checked === true)
  {
    remoteOkCheck.checked = false;
    
    if( !remoteOkCheck.checked === true)
    {
      // this works
      console.log('remote is switched off');
    }
    
    remoteOk.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    remoteOk.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 59, 222);
  border-image: initial;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: rgb(0, 59, 222);
}

#remote-ok{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

#remote-ok.active{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group standard">
  <label class="control-label" for="id_location">Location</label>
  <input placeholder="Toronto" type="text" name="location" id="id_location" required="" class=" form-control standard" maxlength="200">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" id="remote-only"><input type="checkbox" id="remote-only-check" value=""><span>Remote Only</span></label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline active" id="remote-ok"><input type="checkbox" id="remote-ok-check" value=""><span>Remote OK</span></label>
</div>
```